# Google Sheets - Applying Fill Colour to Several Individual Cells (without having to use dropdown menu)

Tags: google-sheets

Very *very* minor thing I find annoying and / or haven't figured out what I am doing wrong on Google Sheets.

In Excel, when you turn a cell a specific colour, it remembers the last colour you used, so you can click on the colour fill button and it will apply the same colour, rather than having to re-select it in the dropdown menu (see example screenshot of 'Excel').

[image: Excel]

In Google Sheets, the button shows the current colour of the cell (which I think is self-evident anyway), so I have to go into the drop down menu each time to select the new colour (see example screenshot of 'Sheets').

[image: Sheets]

So my question is - is there a way for Google Sheets to retain the last colour used on the fill colour button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be handy, is the format painter (Circled icon). Not perfect, but may save you 1 or more clicks. Just select the cell you want to copy the format, click on the format painter and click on the new cell or range (with control) you want to apply the format.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have used this in Excel so not sure it didn't occur to me to use in Sheets. My colleague also pointed out that F4 will copy the last action made, so can copy formatting that way too

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately no. in Google Sheets you always need to enter the color picker so this can be done by a minimum of two clicks

[image: 0]

the only tool that remembers color is **border color**